# setState not updating value with object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

This is my initial state:

```
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([
    { answer: "Answer 1", isCorrect: false, points: 0 },
  ]);
```

I am adding input field dynamically and initially there will be one field. There is an Add button through which I can add more fields and remove button with that I can remove fields. But the problem I'm facing, after submitting the value I want to clear all the fields and there should be only one field as it was initially.Suppose if I add 4 fields and after submitting there should be only one. But when I'm trying to do that its not working but add, remove and even setting empty the state is working but setting only one field is not working.I'm mapping depending on `inputList` value but still after submitting I'm getting all the fields. If I have added 4 fields then after submitting also its 4. The state value is not being changed at all.

ADD more function:

```
 const handleAddClick = () => {
    let count = inputList.length;
    let newfield = {
      answer: `Answer ${count + 1}`,
      isCorrect: false,
      points: 0,
    };
    setInputList([...inputList, newfield]);
  };
```

remove function:

```
 const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    let list = [...inputList];
    let newList = list.filter((item, ind) => ind !== index);
    setInputList(newList);
  };
```

submit function: **This should reset the state to initial state that is only one field should be there** But not working

```
 const Save = () => {
        setInputList([{ answer: "Answer 1", isCorrect: false, points: 0 }])  
    }
```

I tried to do loop also for deleting every index but it only removes one no matter how many times the loop runs

Whole Component:

```
    import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";
import React from "react";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import Radio from "@mui/material/Radio";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import Switch from "@mui/material/Switch";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { useState } from "react";
import PlusSign from "../../../../Files/img/plus.png";
import Header from "../../../Header/Header";
import Topbar from "../../../Topbar/Topbar";
import styles from "../MultipleResponse/MultipleResponse.module.scss";
import QuestionEditor from "../../Editor/QuestionEditor/QuestionEditor";
import ReactTag from "../../TagInput/ReactTag";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import axios from "axios";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import AnswerEditor from "../../Editor/AnswerEditor/AnswerEditor";
import SelectComp from "../../SelectComp/SelectComp";
import {
  timeOptions,
  categoryOptions,
  difficultyLevelOptions,
} from "../../../../utils/constants";
import { RadioGroup } from "@mui/material";
import Snackbars from "../../../Assesment/MyAssesment/Snackbar";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function MultipleChoice() {
  const baseURL = "http://localhost:5000/api/question";
  const [distributePoints, setDistributePoints] = useState(false);
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([
    { answer: "Answer 1", isCorrect: false, points: 0 },
  ]);
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState("");
  const [tags, setTag] = useState([]);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [time, setTime] = useState("");
  const [difficultyLevel, setdifficultyLevel] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [whatToLook, setwhatToLook] = useState("");
  const [questionRelevent, setQuestionRelevent] = useState("");
  const [shuffle, setShuffle] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [loading2, setLoading2] = useState(false);
  const [snackText, setSnackText] = useState("");
  const [severity,setSeverity]=useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tempData"));
    if (items) {
      setTitle(items[0].title);
      setdifficultyLevel(items[0].level);
      setwhatToLook(items[0].whatToLookFor);
      setQuestionRelevent(items[0].whyQuestionIsRelevant);
      setTag(items[0].tags);
      setTime(items[0].time);
      setInputList(items[0].answers);
      setCategory(items[0].category);
      setQuestion(items[0].detail);
      setShuffle(items[0].shuffleAnswers);
      setDistributePoints(items[0].distributePoints);
      setValue(items[0].radioValue);
    }
  }, []);

  const [snack, setSnack] = React.useState(false);

  const closeSnackbar = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }

    setSnack(false);
  };

  const IOSSwitch = styled((props) => (
    <Switch
      focusVisibleClassName=".Mui-focusVisible"
      disableRipple
      {...props}
    />
  ))(({ theme }) => ({
    width: 40,
    height: 24,
    padding: 0,
    marginRight: 10,
    "& .MuiSwitch-switchBase": {
      padding: 0,
      margin: 2,
      transitionDuration: "300ms",
      "&.Mui-checked": {
        transform: "translateX(16px)",
        color: "#fff",
        "& + .MuiSwitch-track": {
          backgroundColor:
            theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? "#3699FF" : "#3699FF",
          opacity: 1,
          border: 0,
        },
        "&.Mui-disabled + .MuiSwitch-track": {
          opacity: 0.5,
        },
      },
      "&.Mui-focusVisible .MuiSwitch-thumb": {
        color: "#33cf4d",
        border: "6px solid #fff",
      },
      "&.Mui-disabled .MuiSwitch-thumb": {
        color:
          theme.palette.mode === "light"
            ? theme.palette.grey[100]
            : theme.palette.grey[600],
      },
      "&.Mui-disabled + .MuiSwitch-track": {
        opacity: theme.palette.mode === "light" ? 0.7 : 0.3,
      },
    },
    "& .MuiSwitch-thumb": {
      boxSizing: "border-box",
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
      backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
    },
    "& .MuiSwitch-track": {
      borderRadius: 26 / 2,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === "light" ? "#E9E9EA" : "#39393D",
      opacity: 1,
      transition: theme.transitions.create(["background-color"], {
        duration: 500,
      }),
    },
  }));

  const switchHandler = (event) => {
    setDistributePoints(event.target.checked);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index]["answer"] = e;
    setInputList(list);
  };

  const handlePointChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setInputList(list);
  };
  const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    let list = [...inputList];
    let newList = list.filter((item, ind) => ind !== index);
    setInputList(newList);
  };

  const handleAddClick = () => {
    let count = inputList.length;
    let newfield = {
      answer: `Answer ${count + 1}`,
      isCorrect: false,
      points: 0,
    };
    setInputList([...inputList, newfield]);
  };

  const SaveAndAddAnother = () => {
    setLoading2(true);
    const newInputList = inputList.map(({ points, ...rest }) => {
      return rest;
    });
    try {
      axios
        .post(baseURL, {
          questionType: "MULTIPLE_CHOICE",
          time: time.toString(),
          title: title,
          level: difficultyLevel,
          detail: question,
          category: category,
          tags: tags,
          whatToLookFor: whatToLook,
          whyQuestionIsRelevant: questionRelevent,
          answers: distributePoints ? inputList : newInputList,
          distributePoints: distributePoints,
          shuffleAnswers: shuffle,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          setLoading(false);
          if (response.data.result === 1) {
            setSnack(true);
            setSeverity('success')
            setTimeout(() => {
              setLoading2(false);
            }, 1000);
            setSnackText("Question added successfully");
            setTime("");
            setTitle("");
            setdifficultyLevel("");
            setQuestion("");
            setCategory("");
            setTag([]);
            setwhatToLook("");
            setQuestionRelevent("");
            setDistributePoints(false);
            setShuffle(false);
            setValue("A");
            let newList = [{ answer: "Answer 1", isCorrect: false, points: 0 }];
            setInputList(newList);
            localStorage.removeItem("tempData");
          } else {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          // Handle error
          setLoading2(false);
          setSnack(true)
          setSnackText("Error Adding question")
          setSeverity('error')
        });
    } catch (e) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  const Save = () => {
    setInputList([{ answer: "Answer 1", isCorrect: false, points: 0 }])




    // setSnack(true);
    // setSnackText("Question Saved as draft");
    // setSeverity('success')
    // setLoading(true);
    // const localData = [
    //   {
    //     questionType: "MULTIPLE_CHOICE",
    //     time: time.toString(),
    //     title: title,
    //     level: difficultyLevel,
    //     detail: question,
    //     category: category,
    //     tags: tags,
    //     whatToLookFor: whatToLook,
    //     whyQuestionIsRelevant: questionRelevent,
    //     answers: inputList,
    //     distributePoints: distributePoints,
    //     shuffleAnswers: shuffle,
    //     radioValue: value,
    //   },
    // ];
    // localStorage.setItem("tempData", JSON.stringify(localData));
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   setLoading(false);
    // }, 2000);
  };

  const questionText = (value) => {
    setQuestion(value);
  };
  const selectedTags = (tags) => {
    setTag(tags);
  };
  const handleTitle = (e) => {
    setTitle(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleTime = (e) => {
    setTime(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleDifficulty = (e) => {
    setdifficultyLevel(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleCategory = (e) => {
    setCategory(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleWhatToLookFor = (e) => {
    setwhatToLook(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleQuestionRelevent = (e) => {
    setQuestionRelevent(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleShuffle = (event) => {
    setShuffle(event.target.checked);
  };

  function handleRadioButton(event, i) {
    if (event.target.value === value) {
      setValue("");
    } else {
      setValue(event.target.value);
    }
    const list = [...inputList];
    Object.keys(list).forEach((key) => {
      list[key]["isCorrect"] = false;
    });
    list[i]["isCorrect"] = true;
    setInputList(list);
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
      <Header />
      <Topbar
        questionType="Multiple-response"
        loading={loading}
        loading2={loading2}
        SaveAndAddAnother={SaveAndAddAnother}
        save={Save}
      />
      <div className={styles.Container}>
        <div className={styles.questionContainer}>
          <div className={styles.left}>
            <p className={styles.question}>Question</p>

            <div className={styles.input}>
              <TextField
                variant="standard"
                InputProps={{
                  disableUnderline: true,
                }}
                className={styles.title}
                placeholder="Title.."
                value={title}
                onChange={(e) => handleTitle(e)}
              />
              <QuestionEditor
                question={question}
                questionText={questionText}
                theme="snow"
              />
            </div>

            <div className={styles.category}>
              <ReactTag tags={tags} selectedTags={selectedTags} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.right}>
            <div className={styles.rightText}>
              <span className={styles.heading}>Select the right answer</span>
              <div>
                <IOSSwitch
                  checked={distributePoints}
                  onChange={switchHandler}
                />
                <span className={styles.instructinHeading}>
                  Distribute points across answers
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.answers}>
              <div className={styles.radio}>
                <FormControl style={{ display: "flex", flex: 1 }}>
                  <RadioGroup
                    aria-labelledby="demo-controlled-radio-buttons-group"
                    name="controlled-radio-buttons-group"
                    value={value}
                  >
                    {inputList.map((x, i) => {
                      return (
                        <div key={i}>
                          <div key={i} className={styles.options}>
                            {!distributePoints ? (
                              <FormControlLabel
                                key={i}
                                value={x.answer}
                                control={
                                  <Radio
                                    onClick={(e) => handleRadioButton(e, i)}
                                  />
                                }
                                defaultChecked={false}
                              />
                            ) : (
                              ""
                            )}
                            <div className="editor">
                              <AnswerEditor
                                handleAnswer={handleInputChange}
                                index={i}
                                theme="bubble"
                                val={x.answer}
                              />
                            </div>
                            {distributePoints ? (
                              <div className={styles.inputCounter}>
                                <TextField
                                  variant="standard"
                                  name="points"
                                  InputProps={{
                                    disableUnderline: true,
                                    type: "number",
                                  }}
                                  inputProps={{
                                    min: 0,
                                    style: { textAlign: "center" },
                                  }}
                                  value={x.points}
                                  onChange={(e) => handlePointChange(e, i)}
                                />
                              </div>
                            ) : (
                              ""
                            )}

                            {inputList.length > 1 && (
                              <IconButton
                                onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}
                                className={styles.icon}
                              >
                                <DeleteIcon
                                  sx={{ fontSize: 24, color: "#3699FF" }}
                                />
                              </IconButton>
                            )}
                          </div>

                          {inputList.length - 1 === i && (
                            <div className={styles.bottomItemContainer}>
                              {distributePoints ? (
                                <div className={styles.pointsInfoText}>
                                  Allocate points across answers. Give the best
                                  answer 5 points
                                </div>
                              ) : (
                                ""
                              )}

                              {!inputList.some((el) => el.isCorrect === true) &&
                              !distributePoints ? (
                                <div className={styles.pointsInfoText}>
                                  Select the correct answer
                                </div>
                              ) : (
                                ""
                              )}

                              <div
                                style={{
                                  display: "flex",
                                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                                }}
                              >
                                <button
                                  onClick={handleAddClick}
                                  type="button"
                                  className={styles.addButton}
                                >
                                  <img src={PlusSign} alt="" /> Add another
                                  answer
                                </button>

                                <div className={styles.label}>
                                  <Checkbox
                                    checked={shuffle}
                                    onChange={handleShuffle}
                                    style={{ color: "#00A3FF" }}
                                  />
                                  Shuffle answer
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                  </RadioGroup>
                </FormControl>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.itemContainer}>
          <div className={styles.timeContainer}>
            <SelectComp
              handleChange={handleTime}
              title="Time to answer the question"
              val={time}
              optionData={timeOptions}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.timeContainer}>
            <SelectComp
              handleChange={handleCategory}
              title="Question Category"
              val={category}
              optionData={categoryOptions}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.itemContainer}>
          <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>What to look for in the answer?</div>
          <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>Why is this question relevant?</div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.itemContainer}>
          <div className={styles.releventText}>
            <TextField
              variant="standard"
              InputProps={{
                disableUnderline: true,
              }}
              className={styles.text}
              placeholder="What to look for in the answer..."
              value={whatToLook}
              onChange={(e) => handleWhatToLookFor(e)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.releventText}>
            <TextField
              variant="standard"
              InputProps={{
                disableUnderline: true,
              }}
              className={styles.text}
              placeholder="Why is this question relevant.."
              value={questionRelevent}
              onChange={(e) => handleQuestionRelevent(e)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.itemContainer}>
          <div className={styles.difficultyLevel}>
            <SelectComp
              handleChange={handleDifficulty}
              title="Difficulty Level"
              val={difficultyLevel}
              optionData={difficultyLevelOptions}
            />
          </div>
          {/* <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>Why is this question relevant?</div> */}
        </div>
        <div className={styles.bottomInfo}>
          <div className={styles.element}>
            <div className={styles.circle}></div>
            <div className={styles.text}>
              How should I formate my questions?
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.element}>
            <div className={styles.circle2}></div>
            <div className={styles.text}>
              {" "}
              How do I use the question editor?
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.element}>
            <div className={styles.circle3}></div>
            <div className={styles.text}>How do I use the formula editor?</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {snack && (
        <Snackbars
          text={snackText}
          snack={snack}
          closeSnackbar={closeSnackbar}
          severity={severity}
        />
      )}
      {/* <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>{JSON.stringify(inputList)}</div> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It's much easier to help when I can see and run a complete minimal snippet rather than guessing how all of this fits together.

Comment: Would you like to connect over google meet to resolve it together.

Comment: here is the whole component https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-bogdan-9dummd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: sure that would be better @AtulBhatt

Comment: https://meet.google.com/uyi-ckoq-rri

I'll be waiting for 10 mins here. You codesandbox is missing a lot of stuff to run

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my problem. I was stuck here for a long. Thanks a lot @AtulBhatt